# Engine Performance Data for GE F414-400

Tags: aircraft-performance, engine, turbofan, fa-18, lockheed-martin-x-59-quesst

I am currently in Capstone for ASE, and for our course we have been tasked with reverse engineering the X-59 QueSST created by NASA and Lockheed Martin. I am the propulsion lead for our team and I have been able to gather the bare minimum specifications of the engine like thrust, SFC, pressure ratios, and weights and such. I am wanting to run a parametric cycle analysis on the mixed exhaust turbofan engines and to do this per Mattingly's PCA method in aircraft engine design book, there are a lot of input parameters such as the bleed air flow rate, mixing ratios, and bunch of other specific variables. Does anyone have engine performance data for the GE F414-400 engine? Any information on it's design specifications or actual data of the installed or uninstalled engine would be a gold mine in verifying that my PCA of the engine is accurate. Currently, I am using general values for all turbofan engines for the variables I can't find. Is there any website or resource that contains this type of data? Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide.